# How to make a synchronous web service call

Tags: java, web-services, synchronous

How to call a web service synchronously, i.e request,response. when we call web service the caller should wait until he gets the response. Kindly help me with sample.

Comment: http://www.eaipatterns.com/ComposedMessagingWS.html has the detailed explanation.

Comment: Just have the write followed by the read in the same method. The read will wait until it gets a response.

Comment: Contract Last and Contract First. When using a contract-last approach, you start with the Java code, and let the Web service contract (WSDL, see sidebar) be generated from that. When using contract-first, you start with the WSDL contract, and use Java to implement said contract. If you want to use Contract-First, take a look at this:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/why-contract-first.html

Answer (score 2):

Read up on the [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html#Final_Source_Code) (for REST services) or [Spring WebServices](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html#d4e1784) (for SOAP services)